# How to keep a icon checked after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html

so i made a div with a icon, and when the user clicks the icon the id of a movie is pushed in the local storage. So when the user refresh the page i want that the icon to remain a full heart and not an empty heart. How could i do that?

```js
var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites')) || [];
// add class 'fav' to each favorite
const whiteHeart = 'fa fa-heart-o fa-2x';
const blackHeart = 'fa fa-heart fa-2x';
const button = document.querySelector('#heart_icon');

$('#heart').click(function() {
  const movie_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  index = favorites.indexOf(movie_id);
  if (!movie_id) return;
  // item is not favorite
  if (index == -1) {
    favorites.push(movie_id);
    button.className = blackHeart;
    // item is already favorite
  } else {
    favorites.splice(index, 1);
    button.className = whiteHeart;
  }
  // store array in local storage
  JSON.parse(localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites)));
})
```

```html
<div id="heart" data-id="ID1"> <i id="heart_icon" class="fa fa-heart-o fa-2x"></i> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that if you have more than one heart, you need to use a class

```
$('.heart').click(function() {
```

In your current code you need to

1. Change
   `JSON.parse(localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites))` to just  `localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites))`
2. onload run over stored favs

Suggested code https://plungjan.name/SO/heartslocalstorage.html

```js
let favorites;
const toggleIcon = ($icon, id) => {
  const isFav = favorites.indexOf(id) !== -1; // or includes for non-IE11 (polyfill on my site)
  $icon
    .toggleClass("fa-heart-o", !isFav)
    .toggleClass("fa-heart", isFav); // swap classes
};
$(function() {
  favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites')) || [];

  $('.heart').on("click", function() {
    const id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    const $icon = $(this).find("i");
    if (favorites.indexOf(id) === -1) favorites.push(id); // save the movie
    else {
      const index = favorites.indexOf(id); // get the movie position
      favorites.splice(index, 1); // and delete it from favourites
    }
    toggleIcon($icon, id);
    // store array in local storage
    localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites));
  })

  $('.heart[data-id]').each(function() { // set the classes on ALL hearts
    const id = $(this).data("id");
    const $icon = $(this).find("i");
    toggleIcon($icon, id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="heart" data-id="ID1"> <i id="heart_icon" class="fa fa-heart-o fa-2x"></i> </div>
<div class="heart" data-id="ID2"> <i id="heart_icon" class="fa fa-heart-o fa-2x"></i> </div>
<div class="heart" data-id="ID3"> <i id="heart_icon" class="fa fa-heart-o fa-2x"></i> </div>
```

Comment: this code: `$('.heart_icon[data-id]').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass(favorites.indexOf($(this).data("id")) === -1 ? whiteHeart : blackHeart)
  })` what is doing?

Comment: It sets all hearts classes to either whiteheart or black heart depending on their presencein favourites

Comment: If the code gives error it’s because I cannot test localStorage scripts here at Stackoverflow

Comment: @Alex98 See comments I added

Comment: @Alex98 I updated to more reliable code. Please see [running example](https://plungjan.name/SO/heartslocalstorage.html)

Comment: It was fun, but I was not happy with just posting untested code. When I tested I could see it did not work well with YOUR html and I wanted to test with more than one heart